# problemas para obtener una variable

Tags: php, url, seo

estoy intentando traer una variable que obtengo mediante **GET** en otro archivo **php** antes del **html** en mi `index.php`, es decir desde mi index php mediante un enlace traigo un contenido a mi index ya que mi aplicación esta en módulos y estoy usando URL amigables pero necesito generar una descripción en la etiqueta `meta description`  del contenido que traigo de mi archivo php.

La aplicación funciona en módulos en php dividida

después de la cabecera

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Ejemplo</title>

//some more javascript tags and css....
</head>
<body>
<header>

//navbar etc...
</header>
```

luego obtengo la variable view de mi archivo **htaccess** para traer los módulos y que las URL sean amigables...

```
<?php

      if (isset($_GET["view"])) {

      $view=explode("/",$_GET["view"]);
         echo"<input type='hidden' id='section' value='$view[0]'>";

            include"modules/".$view[0]."-view.php";
            $title=$view[0];
            //echo" <script src='URLSERVERjs/script.js'></script>";
      }else{

         include"modules/inicio-view.php";

      } 

  ?>
```

Entonces en el modulo de inicio es decir la pagina `index.php` tengo algunos posts que obtengo mediante una consulta a la BD lo resultados de dicha consulta los imprimo en una etiqueta `a` para que me lleve a ver ese post en un modulo.
La cosa es que una vez yo doy clic a ese enlace para ir a ver el post necesito traer una variable a la cabecera de mi archivo `index.php` para agregar la descripción de ese post a la etiqueta `meta description`

*Esto con la finalidad de posicionamiento del SEO en los resultados de búsquedas en **google***

Intente lo siguiente en la cabecera de mi index con `isset` de **php** pero no me funciona

```
if (isset($description)) {
   $description=$description;

}else{

  $description="nada";
}
```

aunque en el modulo de ver ese post declaro la varible description para luego intentar leerla en la cabecera esto siempre me imprime **nada**

Comment: Cuando vas al enlace del post, no vuelves a obtener todos los datos de ese post? Si es así, porque no tomas la `description` de la consulta?

Comment: claro que si, obtenfo todo en una consulta el problemas es eque en el header intento inprimir esa varible pero no sale